# Reading child node of JSON response using SwiftyJSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

My JSON response looks like this:

```
{
data: {
   type: "collections",
   id: "dc165b3f-3600-486f-aa0b-d4719b18bb61",
   attributes: {},
   relationships: {
        shows: {},
        slides: {
        links: {
          self: "https://stage-api.cde.com/networks/online/j/collections/dc165b3f-3600-486f-aa0b-d4719b18bb61/relationships/slides",
related: "https://stage-api.cde.com/networks/online/j/collections/dc165b3f-3600-486f-aa0b-d4719b18bb61/slides"
},
      data: [
        {
          type: "slides",
          id: "935d2313-4816-44a9-a65a-06a98af2d730"
        },
        {
          type: "slides",
          id: "daf02fda-b356-46df-b1d0-8c3212d826bf"
        },
        {
          type: "slides",
          id: "77bbb082-5976-450a-bb48-fda9d2a44e80"
        }
   ]
},
videos: {},
collections: {}
},
links: {}
}
}
```

and I need to get the value of all `id` which are present within the `slides` node under the `data` array. I am using the **[SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)** framework.

Any help is highly appreciated. If not SwiftyJSON then please advice other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import SwiftyJSON

let json: JSON = ...
let data = json["data"]["relationships"]["slides"]["data"]
guard let dataArray = data.array else {
    fatalError("data array NOT FOUND")
}
for child in dataArray {
    guard let id = child["id"].string else {
        fatalError("id NOT FOUND")
    }
    print("id: \(id)")
}
```

Comment: is it possible to share codes how to do this with DispatchSemaphore(value: 0) so that I can get the value outside of the function when used with :
 Alamofire.request(title, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON{ response in switch response.result { case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                let data = json["data"]["relationships"]["slides"]["data"]
                for child in data.array! {
                    let id = child["id"].string!
                   print("id: \(id)")}.
Sorry , I am new to this.

Comment: @mizanrahman Please ask a new question with your current issue and link back to this one. You will get faster/better results that way ;)